# jQuery.browser.msie replacement deprecated code

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, deprecated

I've recently started upgrading jQuery for a clients website and come across some legacy code using deprecated jQuery.  Consider:

```
jQuery(setClass).css((jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version < 7 ? '' : 'min-') + 'height', maxHeight + 'px');
```

I'd like to achieve the same thing using a modern alternative rather than spoofing my jQuery by re-enabling .browser.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Best way would be to instead set that css style in a stylesheet. You can then override it for IE6 using a separate stylesheet included with conditional comments. *Or you can ask your client to drop support for IE6*.

Comment: Thanks, I've confirmed that IE6 support is no longer needed, and have since removed all known instances of .browser.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional comments with multiple stylesheets would likely be a better way of handling this, however, I would suggest removing the need to handle this by dropping support for IE6. And while you're at it, drop IE7.

Both IE6 and IE7 have dropped to a point where it generally isn't worth supporting them anymore. If a particular system only runs properly on IE7, IE8+ can still support said systems using compatibility mode.

If dropping support and/or conditional comments aren't applicable, another option would be to include the jQuery Migrate plugin which re-introduces `.browser`.